# Cannot install tensorflow==1.13.1 with python 3.6.0 in a pyenv virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I have Ubuntu 20.04 which has python 3.8 installed.

I need python 3.6 for a project that I work on because the project requires tensorflow==1.13.1.

I installed Pyenv and installed python 3.6.0.

Inside the project directory I ran `pyenv local 3.6.0` and then I created a virtual environment with the command `pyenv virtualenv 3.6.0 Fathom_pyenv`. I then activate the virtual env with `pyenv activate Fathom_pyenv`.

But when I try to install tensorflow==1.13.1, I get the same error.

```
(Fathom_pyenv) tombrown@tombrown:~/git/Fathom$ pip3 install tensorflow==1.13.1
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1
```

Would anybody know what I am doing incorrect?

I checked by .bashrc file, I have no `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` environment variables.

When I run `pyenv versions`, this is what I get:

```
(Fathom_pyenv) tombrown@tombrown:~/git/Fathom$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.6.0
  3.6.0/envs/Fathom_pyenv
* Fathom_pyenv (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
(Fathom_pyenv) johnbrad@johnbrad-desk:~/git/Fathom$
```

thank you

Comment: Create a new env with Python=3.5.6. it worked with tensoflow==1.13.2.

Answer (score 1):

When installing `tensorflow` in a `pyenv` virtual Python environment, I also encountered the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow / No matching distribution found for tensorflow."

I found a solution that worked for me. When `pyenv` creates an environment, that environment comes with `wheel` installed. For most packages, this doesn't pose a problem, but `tensorflow` needs `wheel` in order to be installed. I recommend trying the following steps:

1. With the environment activated, check to see whether your `pyenv` environment has `wheel` installed.

```bash
$ pip list
```

2. If you see that `wheel` is not in that list of packages, install it with pip.

```bash
$ pip install wheel
```

3. Now try installing tensorflow. I'm on Mac and I was having a lot of trouble, so I had success with this installation:

```bash
$ pip install tensorflow-macos
```

By simply adding `wheel` to my `pyenv` virtual environment before installing `tensorflow`, I was able to fix the problem. Please let me know if this type of solution worked for you too.